# Fixed spawn points in multiplayer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can I change this `Random.Range` to fixed points and still send the data to the socket?

I want to have two fixed spawn points at two different positions. And, I am new to Unity. Can someone help me with making fixed Spawn points?

```
    public Transform[] spawnPoints; //stores the spawn points
    
    //makes the draw of a point for the player to be  spawn
    int index = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);
    
    public void EmitJoin(){
    //store player's skin
    data["model"] = CharacterChoiceManager.instance.current_model.ToString();
    data["posX"] = spawnPoints[index].position.x.ToString();
    data["posY"] = spawnPoints[index].position.y.ToString();
    data["posZ"] = spawnPoints[index].position.z.ToString();
    
    Application.ExternalCall("socket.emit", "JOIN",new JSONObject(data));
```

Comment: Consider creating a game object where you want your spawn point to be.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Random.Range(min, max)` returns a number between min and max.

If you want to have the same `spawnPoint` for a user, you would need to store the value of `index` that you get the first time.

The implementation will be different depending on your code.

Options:

- Add a property to your player class to save the `index`
- Create a list/dictionary/hashset to save an index for each player
- ...

Comment: I want two fixed spawn points in different positions. And can you help me to make the specific modifications? I am quite new to c#. Much Appreciated.

Comment: edit you question to give more context, otherwise it's difficult to help you

Comment: I have edited it. Can you be able to help me?